Adds extra www when entering django admin panel
My website worked very well yesterday but today i have a problem.
My website is https://www.622health.com.tr
When i write https://www.622health.com.tr/admin and click enter,
Its redirect to https://www.www.622health.com.tr/admin
I made some redirect things for example 622health.com.tr to www.622health.com.tr , but this problem i removed all redirects but still i have an error.
How can i fix this.
I use ai for this but nothing.

When I try in my browser it does not add the extra www, though since I'm not logged in, this behavior might be different.  Could it be browser caching issue?  Try clearing the cache for the site, and trying again.

i tried three different browser and after your comment i try mozilla, yes you are right, caching issue. Thanks my friend.
